# SQL Server - Understanding stored procedure call

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powerbi

I try to understand an application based on a SQL Server database.

For a certain functionality, it executes a stored procedure using the following query:

```
declare @p3 dbo.IdsTableType
insert into @p3 values(1)

declare @p9 dbo.IdsTableType
insert into @p9 values(1)
insert into @p9 values(6)
insert into @p9 values(0)

exec StatisticView174 
          @TimeFrameStart = '2019-01-01 00:00:00',
          @TimeFrameEnd = '2020-01-01 00:00:00',
          @IdStocks = @p3,
          @IdLng = 1, @GuiLng = N'en', @IdUser = 213, 
          @OnlyOwn = 0, @IdAddress = NULL, 
          @IdCompanys = @p9, @IdProject = NULL, @HourMinDiv = 60
```

Can anybody explain to me how the table variables `@p3` and `@p9` are passed as parameters?

How could I replace them avoiding the declaration?

I want to use the query for PowerBI, but there I am not able to use variable declarations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently `StatisticView174` expects [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), which is a way of passing in 'arrays' of values. In your use case, if these arrays have a fixed, limited length, then you might consider wrapping your code in a new stored procedure (with only scalar parameters), and use that in PowerBI. Would that cover your needs?

Comment: It _may_ be possible, but we need to see the definition of `IdsTableType` and `StatisticView174` first.

Comment: "I want to use the query for PowerBI, but there I am not able to use variable declarations." - why do you say this? PowerBI supports query parameters which you can use with sprocs directly or with any batch query).

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL Server database

Navigate to

Programmability -> Types -> User Defined Table types

You will find the IdsTableType.

We can create User defined Table types as parameter and pass table as a parameter to a stored procedure.